# Fill in checkbox array with new collection

Tags: json, forms, backbone.js

I'm trying to fill a checkbox array with a JSON array from the request URL. I have read the documentation and I see that I could do this with models and collections, but I'm not sure how to start. If anyone could show me what the path is, I would appreciate it. This is my code:

```
var mBox = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
var cBox = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mBox,
    url: 'http://localhost/oferta/prueba1/?json=get_taxonomy&taxonomy=habilidad&dev=1'
});
var Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        id:                     {},
        nombre:                 {},
        apellidos:              {},
        email:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'email', validators: ['required', validateEmail] },
        telefono:               { type: 'Text', dataType: 'tel', validators: ['required'] },
        nacionalidad:           { type: 'Select', options: ['Española', 'Extranjera'] },
        link1:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Reel', dataType: 'url' },
        link2:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Web/Blog', dataType: 'url' },
        otros:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'url' },
        skills:                 { type: 'Checkboxes', options: new cBox() },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start. What I think might be tripping you up is how the data is actually fetched and placed into the collection. You have a defined a `url` property on `cBox`, your collection, but that itself does not actually *get* any data from the server. You have to call Backbone's [`Collection.fetch()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) method to get the data and put it into the collection.

I would do something like this:

```
cBoxCheckboxes = new cBox(); // create a new cbox, but there is no data in here yet
cBoxCheckboxes.fetch(); // make a get request to the server (at the url you've specified) to get the data
var Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        id:                     {},
        nombre:                 {},
        apellidos:              {},
        email:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'email', validators: ['required', validateEmail] },
        telefono:               { type: 'Text', dataType: 'tel', validators: ['required'] },
        nacionalidad:           { type: 'Select', options: ['Española', 'Extranjera'] },
        link1:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Reel', dataType: 'url' },
        link2:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Web/Blog', dataType: 'url' },
        otros:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'url' },
        skills:                 { type: 'Checkboxes', options: cBoxCheckboxes /* the collection with the data in it */ },
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, thats work but it doesnt assign the result to options, i can see the result by the console but its not there... why?

Comment: I did a parse function which gives back its a array with the elements which it will appear on options, but i dont get anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

that solutions doesnt work like, i would like.. I rewrite the code and i do this:

```
var mmyBox = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var cmyBox = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mmyBox,
    url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/oferta/prueba1/?json=get_taxonomy&taxonomy=habilidad&dev=1',
    parse: function (resp, xhr) {
        console.log(resp.terms);
        return resp.terms;
    }
});

function validateEmail(str) {
    var regex = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?");

    return regex.test(str) ? null : 'Invalid email';
}

var Form = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        id:                     {},
        nombre:                 {},
        apellidos:              {},
        email:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'email', validators: ['required', validateEmail] },
        telefono:               { type: 'Text', dataType: 'tel', validators: ['required'] },
        nacionalidad:           { type: 'Select', options: ['Española', 'Extranjera'] },
        link1:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Reel', dataType: 'url' },
        link2:                  { type: 'Text', title: 'Enlace a Web/Blog', dataType: 'url' },
        otros:                  { type: 'Text', dataType: 'url' },
        skills:                 { type: 'Checkboxes', options: new cmyBox() },
    }
});
```

The parse function gives back the array terms from the json.

```
Array
{
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 3,
  "terms": [
    {
      "id": 11,
      "slug": "artist",
      "title": "artist",
      "description": "",
      "post_count": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 13,
      "slug": "medico",
      "title": "medico",
      "description": "",
      "post_count": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "slug": "programador",
      "title": "programador",
      "description": "",
      "post_count": 1
    }
  ]
```

It seems than the new cmyBox doesnt create the new collection. Well that its what i see by console.

Thanks Josh for the answer. Cheers.

Comment: The problem came from the url string. At the last it had a dev tag.. for that reason didnt work.